# Why does my query keep returning everyone as belonging to the same id column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function; in it, it runs a MySQL query to check the viewing user's id, and then select their department's id from that. Then, that department_id is to be passed into the next query, which returns a list of tickets for that specific department_id.

There are two tables involved.

ow_supportcenter_ticket:

```
id, author_id, category_id, department_id, subject, text, status, created, updated, requested_deletion
```

ow_supportcenter_department_user:

```
department_id, user_id
```

This function I'm working on is on the function for a page where assigned users view tickets they can answer for others. In the backend, an Admin assigns them to a department, which is the table department_user. When a user views this page, it's supposed to return their department_id, then pass that result as a parameter into the query that returns the tickets. Just like this:

```
    static function get_mod_list($yo){
    $tt = SupportCenterDB::table_ticket();
    $dp = SupportCenterDB::table_department();
    $d = OW::getDbo();
    return $d->queryForList("SELECT {$tt}.id, category_id, subject, requested_deletion, {$dp}.text, {$tt}.department_id, updated, status FROM {$tt}
    JOIN {$dp} ON {$tt}.department_id = '{$dp}.text'
    WHERE department_id = '".$d->escapeString($yo)."'
    ORDER BY updated DESC;");
}
```

And here's where the $yo comes from:

```
    static function get_department_by_user($id){
    $d=OW::getDbo();
    $res = $d->query("SELECT department_id FROM ".SupportCenterDB::table_department_user()." WHERE user_id ='".$d->escapeString($id)."';");
    return $res;

}
```

However, two problems are arising for me. The biggest one: every user, regardless of their assigned department_id, is returned as being in department_id = 1. When I run the query in phpMyAdmin, it returns the data as it should. When I run it via the website end, it returns department_id = 1 for EVERY user, regardless of their assigned id. Secondly: even with department_id 1, which is an existing department, tickets still aren't being returned.

Comment: **Warning:** You might be open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $yo is either 1 or true if you always have department_id as 1.

When I look at your second function :
Are you sure that the query returns an integer (scalar) and not an array of rows ?
In some framework you would have to add ->scalar() or ->one() to query only one row and return only the field.

I think your function returns an array and when you passed it to the first function it takes it as true because the array is not empty.

An example would be :

```
static function getDepartmentByUser($user_id) {
  return OW::getDbo()
    ->query("SELECT department_id FROM " . SupportCenterDB::table_department_user() . " WHERE user_id ='".$d->escapeString($id)."';")
    ->scalar();
}
```

also you should bind your data for security reason, example may vary with framework :

```
static function getDepartmentByUser($user_id) {
      return OW::getDbo()
        ->query('SELECT department_id FROM :table WHERE user_id = :user_id')
        ->bind(':table', SupportCenterDB::table_department_user())
        ->bind(':user_id', $user_id)
        ->scalar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the flushed out response. I tried applying the ->scalar() to the query, which returned an error that helped me confirm my query was returning as an integer already. Using developer tools in the framework shows me the queries are returning the way they should. For example, in the second query where user_id = #, Admin (whose ID = 1) is returning 1, etc. But the output is not there.

Comment: Oxwall CMS software